# Multiply two ranges from two different excel sheets using VB Express (What is wrong with this?)

Tags: vb.net, excel

whats is wrong with following? (Level:Beginner) I want to add the answers obtained after multiplication of two ranges from two different excel sheets.

```
Dim iRowCounter As Integer
For iRowCounter = 3 To 47

' C3 to C47 from oSheet6
' C22 to C66 from oSheet5

osheet7.Range("A" & iRowCounter - 1).Value = (oSheet5.Range("C" & iRowCounter+19).Value * oSheet6.Range("C" & iRowCounter).Value) + (oSheet5.Range("C" & iRowCounter+20).Value * oSheet6.Range("C" & iRowCounter+1).Value)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant just multiple all the values in the range aginst each other, you need to loop through the range to perform the operation.
So instead of:

```
    oRng7.Value = oRng5.Value * oRng7.Value
```

Try this:

```
 Dim iRowCounter as integer
 For iRowCounter = 3 to 47 then 
      osheet7.Range("B" & iRowCounter -1).value = oSheet5.Range("C" & iRowCounter).value * oSheet6.Range("C" & iRowCounter).value
 next iRowCounter
```

Update:

Your initial formula was:

Sheet7 = Sheet5 * Sheet7

Per your comment, I changed my code to do:

Sheet7 = Sheet5 * Sheet6

Comment: Thanks a lot that works perfectly. So that means even for matrix multiplication we need to loop through the range?

Comment: That writes the 0 in every cell. (Cells in either sheets are not empty or 0) Any clue why? (earlier I thought cells may be empty, but they are not).

Comment: Yes you need to loop through the ranges.
It may be because the code I quoted above says:
Sheet7 = sheet5 * sheet7.
So if sheet7 starts as 0 it will always be 0.
I think what you meant was
Sheet7 = sheet5 * sheet6
I've edited my code above to reflect this, try it now.

Comment: It works. I understood that you meant oSheet6. The mistake was my sheet indexes were incorrect. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Sorry for troubling again. how can I sum these multiplied values and write in oSheet7? I added a multiplication term with (iRowCounter+1). But gives name-double exception.

Comment: Please paste your new code above to update your question so that I may reference it to solve your question.

Comment: When you say "Sum these multiplied values" what values are you trying to sum? (more detail please)
Are you trying to keep a running sum? :
1 = 1 * 1,
5 = 2 * 2 + 1,
14 = 3 * 3 + 5,
30 = 4 * 4 + 14, ect..

Comment: Just saw your new more detailed post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385455/range-multiplication-vb-net-what-is-wrong-with-this-code